# ImportError: cannot import name '_compiler' from 'astropy.utils'

Tags: python-3.x, importerror, astropy

I am currently using a python package which uses astropy within it, and I am getting an error that I have never received while using astropy by itself:

```
File "<ipython-input-14-fe241c5d4a10>", line 1, in <module>
runfile('/Users/colbyostberg/GoogleDrive/Python/Python37/Pandexo_Runner.py', wdir='/Users/colbyostberg/GoogleDrive/Python/Python37')

File "/Users/colbyostberg/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)

File "/Users/colbyostberg/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File "/Users/colbyostberg/GoogleDrive/Python/Python37/Pandexo_Runner.py", line 9, in <module>
import pandexo.engine.justdoit as jdi # THIS IS THE HOLY GRAIL OF PANDEXO

File "/Users/colbyostberg/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandexo/engine/justdoit.py", line 2, in <module>
from pandeia.engine.instrument_factory import InstrumentFactory

File "/Users/colbyostberg/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandeia/engine/instrument_factory.py", line 5, in <module>
from .utils import recursive_subclasses, merge_data

File "/Users/colbyostberg/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandeia/engine/utils.py", line 8, in <module>
import pysynphot as psyn

File "/Users/colbyostberg/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pysynphot/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
from .spectrum import BlackBody, GaussianSource, FlatSpectrum  # noqa

File "/Users/colbyostberg/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pysynphot/spectrum.py", line 15, in <module>
from astropy.io import fits as pyfits

File "/Users/colbyostberg/GoogleDrive/Python/Python37/astropy/__init__.py", line 289, in <module>
_initialize_astropy()

File "/Users/colbyostberg/GoogleDrive/Python/Python37/astropy/__init__.py", line 181, in _initialize_astropy
from .utils import _compiler

ImportError: cannot import name '_compiler' from 'astropy.utils' (/Users/colbyostberg/GoogleDrive/Python/Python37/astropy/utils/__init__.py)
```

I have tried to uninstall and reinstall astropy in a variety of ways but this has not helped, and I have made sure that my PYTHONPATH is correctly pointing towards a directory with numpy in it, but nothing has worked.

Please help.

Comment: It looks like you probably have a messed up `PYTHONPATH`.  You appear to be mixing multiple Python package directories that are incompatible with each other.  On one hand you are running something that is using a Python provided by anaconda (and *probably* should be using `astropy` installed in anaconda).  But then, likely because you have `/Users/colbyostberg/GoogleDrive/Python/Python37/` on your `PYTHONPATH` or something similar) it's using some astropy you have installed in there instead of in anaconda, that is probably incompatible/broken.

Answer (score 0):

The first comment below my question was correct. I mixed up my PYTHONPATH and it was pointing to the wrong directory. I decided to solve this by brute force and reinstalled all of anaconda, as well as deleted the PYTHONPATH I had set previously. Then upon reinstallation everything was fine, and I will never EVER touch or mess with the PYTHONPATH again :)

Comment: Generally you shouldn't have to. This is the problem conda environments are meant to help solve.